mdx-js attempting import that doesn't exist in it's own ecosystem
I'm working on a project that uses mdx and has since the beginning, but after adding fumadocs I'm getting the following error related to @mdx-js/mdx.
Package path ./codes.js is not exported from /Users/bigsexy/Desktop/..../micromark-util-symbol (see exports field in /.../micromark-util-symbol/package.json

The micromark package has the following exports:
"exports": {
    "types": "./dev/index.d.ts",
    "development": "./dev/index.js",
    "default": "./index.js"
    }

But the ./code.js import is being imported in the micromark-util-sanitize-uri package, that is a dependency of @mdx-js.
The thing is that the micromark-util-sanitize-uri package has only 2 meaningful files, an index.js in the root that does not import this import {codes} from 'micromark-util-symbol/codes.js', but also includes a dev directory that has only a single index.js file that does import this code.js export that doesn't exist.
Does anyone know why it's using this dev directory? I'm guessing it has to do with the process.env.NODE_ENV variable, but this is an extremely popular package and there doesn't seem to be any issues related to this, so I'm guessing there has to be something going wrong on my end.
